# Change the Layout of crosstab in iReport 4.0.1

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am using `iReport 4.0.1` to design reports. I want a report by using cross tab. I have formed query and the output also came. But my problem is the default layout design.

My result came like this:

```
       classA classB classC
girls    12    15      18
boys     16    17      13
```

But I want it as:

```
  classA classB classC
   12    15      18    girls 
   16    17      13    boys
```

is there any other layout or ideas available for my output design?

Comment: Did you happen to solve this or yet need a solution??

Comment: Not yet solved. Need Solution.